# Very Large object appears warped and unstable

Tags: 3d-view

I work in imperial unit.

Objects are in 2 inch to 30 ft in sizes environment.

Objects are wonky and the work area is jumpy and uncontrollable.

Please note that my object is far away from origin like 345000 m , 6456524[image] (real world coordinate)

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure what the threshold is, but the farther you get from origin, the more likely you are to experience floating point precision errors. I think at over 6 million units out, you're asking for trouble.

Comment: Is your question how to keep this from happening, or an explanation why?

Comment: I would like to know how to technically remove the problem.

Comment: @Farsh, work smaller. Unless there's a functional need to work at this scale, reduce it all in proportion.

Comment: This [video](https://youtu.be/Q2OGwnRik24) gives a pretty good explainer of the problem.